# How to load a complete Datatables from ajax call?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, datatables

I am trying to fill the table with both column headers and its body with data, however it fails to make the ajax call if.

```
<table id="datatable1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I leave both the head and body empty.
But adding some random title.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Random column title</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

fixes it. Though I mean to add both the column names and the data at the same time from a JSON string and add it to the table it won't let me :

I am also able to load stuff from the database no problem if the proper `aoColumns` and `mData` are established beforehand.

```
var oTable; //datatable reference
var start = 0; //first row's id to load
var qty = 100; //number of rows to load
var DESC = "false"; //load last row first and go down?
var type = "something";
var ajaxURL = GLOBAL_ROUTE + "api/application/datatable/fillTable/" + type + "/" + start + "/" + qty + "/" + DESC;

oTable = $('#datatable1').dataTable({
"sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
"sDom" : '<"top"<"length"l><"search"f><"position">>rt<"bottom"<"info"i><"pages"p>>',
"bProcessing" : false,
"bServerSide" : false,
"sAjaxSource" : ajaxURL,
"bDeferRender" : true,
/*"aoColumns" : [ {
"mData" : "a"
}, {
"mData" : "b"
}, {
"mData" : "c"
}, {
"mData" : "d"
} ]*/
});
alert("asasd"); //this alert is not even reached if no header/body/aoColumns are set.
```

Any way around this without making an ajax call beforehand with the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, I found the way and I'll share it with ya!

All I had to do was change the way I was making the ajax call. Instead of using the datatables "sAjaxSource" parameter to do it, I made my own jquery $.ajax() call to load absolutely everything via json.

First I changed the js code:

```
$.ajax({
"url" : ajaxURL,
"success" : function(json) {
    json.bDestroy = true;
    json.sPaginationType = "full_numbers";
    json.sDom = '<"top"<"length"l><"search"f><"position">>rt<"bottom"<"info"i><"pages"p>>';
    oTable = $('#datatable1').dataTable(json);
},
"dataType" : "json"
});
```

Then I had to make some changes on the data table object.
Here's the java code :

```
import java.util.List;

public class DataTableObject {

String sPaginationType = "";
String sDom = "";
boolean bProcessing = false;
boolean bServerSide = false;
String sEcho;
int iTotalRecords;
private List<Object> aoColumns;
List<Object> aaData;

public String getsPaginationType() {
    return sPaginationType;
}

public void setsPaginationType(String sPaginationType) {
    this.sPaginationType = sPaginationType;
}

public String getsDom() {
    return sDom;
}

public void setsDom(String sDom) {
    this.sDom = sDom;
}

public boolean isbProcessing() {
    return bProcessing;
}

public void setbProcessing(boolean bProcessing) {
    this.bProcessing = bProcessing;
}

public boolean isbServerSide() {
    return bServerSide;
}

public void setbServerSide(boolean bServerSide) {
    this.bServerSide = bServerSide;
}

public int getiTotalRecords() {
    return iTotalRecords;
}

public void setiTotalRecords(int iTotalRecords) {
    this.iTotalRecords = iTotalRecords;
}

public String getsEcho() {
    return sEcho;
}

public void setsEcho(String sEcho) {
    this.sEcho = sEcho;
}

public List<Object> getAaData() {
    return aaData;
}

public void setAaData(List<Object> aaData) {
    this.aaData = aaData;
}

public List<Object> getAoColumns() {
    return aoColumns;
}

public void setAoColumns(List<Object> aoColumns) {
    this.aoColumns = aoColumns;
}
}
```

So yeah, apparently I had to make an outside ajax call, but not two as I thought I might have to do in the end.
Hope this might be of help to someone in the future :)

K, back to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Java on the back end, instead of playing with workarounds, you might want to consider the many examples provided on the JED website that demonstrate how best to work with DataTables on the Java platform.  Check out: http://jed-datatables.net